# Why aren't Temporary Credentials being generated using aws-sdk?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I am using the [aws-sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk) package for node.js and wish to generate temporary credentials.

I have:

```
  AWS.Config.credentials = new AWS.Credentials 'myKey', 'mySecret'
  console.log AWS.Config.credentials

  AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.TemporaryCredentials()
    # DurationSeconds: 1200

  console.log '===='
  console.log AWS.config.credentials
```

However, when I log out the new credentials, it shows `undefined` for the `accessKeyId`. Am I doing something incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AWS.TemporaryCredentials` object refreshes credentials lazily when you make a request. If you want to manually refresh the credentials, you can call `.refresh()` on the credentials object

`AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.TemporaryCredentials();
AWS.config.credentials.refresh();`

Hope this helps!